# Does event-stream supports non utf-8 encoding in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, pipe, chunked-encoding, event-stream

I'm trying to upload and parse file line by line by like the following:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    es = require('event-stream'),
    filePath = './file.txt';

fs.createReadStream(filePath)
  .pipe(new Iconv('cp866', 'windows-1251'))
  .pipe(es.split("\n"))
  .pipe(es.map(function (line, cb) {
     //do something with the line

     cb(null, line)
   }))
  .pipe(res);
```

But unfortunately I get 'line' string in utf-8 encoding. Is it possible to prevent evented-stream change encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

event-stream is based on a older version of streams. And IMO, it tries to do too much.

I would use `through2` instead. But that would require a little extra work.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    thr = require('through2'),
    filePath = './file.txt';

fs.createReadStream(filePath)
  .pipe(new Iconv('cp866', 'windows-1251'))
  .pipe(thr(function(chunk, enc, next){
    var push = this.push
    chunk.toString().split('\n').map(function(line){
      // do something with line 
      push(line)
    })
    next()
  }))
  .pipe(res);
```

Obviously, you could avoid calling `toString()` and manipulate the buffer yourself.

`through2` is a thin wrapper around a `stream.Transform` and gives you more control.